# Change value in a TextView after requests to firebase - Java Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

I make two requests to the Firebase database, and then load the data into the XML. But it doesn't load them and just leaves the default, I suspect it's because I'm not handling asynchronous requests properly in the fragment that Im working (GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter). Can anybody help me?

```
public class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter  {

    Context context;
    static String user, descripcion, username, foto;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference, usersReference;
    TextView title_mod,snipp_mod;
    ImageView imagen_mod;

    public MyInfoWindowAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
            if (!marker.getTitle().toString().equals("Este es mi perfil")) {
                View infoView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_info, null);
                title_mod = infoView.findViewById(R.id.title_mod);
                snipp_mod = infoView.findViewById(R.id.snipp_mod);
                imagen_mod = infoView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_mod);

                LatLng posicionMarker = marker.getPosition();
                String idLocation = String.valueOf(posicionMarker.latitude).replace(".", "") + "_" + String.valueOf(posicionMarker.longitude).replace(".", "");

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chismesinfo");
                databaseReference.child(idLocation).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                            descripcion = snapshot.child("descripcion").getValue(String.class);
                            user = snapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class);

                            usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                            usersReference.child(user).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        DataSnapshot snapshot1 = task.getResult();
                                        username = snapshot1.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                        if (snapshot1.hasChild("profile")) {
                                            foto = snapshot1.child("profile").getValue(String.class);
                                        } else {
                                            foto = null;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

                byte[] imageAsByte = Base64.decode(foto.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsByte, 0, imageAsByte.length);
                imagen_mod.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                snipp_mod.setText(descripcion);
                return infoView;
            }
}
}
```

I was expecting the data to be loaded directly to the interface, but instead I just get the text by default. However, the second time I trigger the event, it does load the data.

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously, as it may take time before it's available. While the data is being loaded, your main code continues - to ensure the user can continue to use the app. Then when the data is loaded, your `onComplete` is called with that data.

What this means in practice is that your `Base64.decode(foto.getBytes()...` gets called before `foto = snapshot1.child("profile").getValue(String.class);` ever runs. If you add some logging or set breakpoints and run in the debugger, you can most easily see this.

---

Let's add some logging to your code and see the result:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chismesinfo");
Log.i("Firebase", "Before calling addOnCompleteListener");
databaseReference.child(idLocation).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        Log.i("Firebase", "Inside onComplete");
    }
});
Log.i("Firebase", "After calling addOnCompleteListener");
```

When you run the above code, you'll get this output:

> Before calling addOnCompleteListener
> After calling addOnCompleteListener
> Inside onComplete

This is probably not the output you expected, but it explains perfectly why your code doesn't work: by the time your `Base64.decode(foto.getBytes()` runs, the `foto` variable doesn't have any value yet.

---

To avoid this problem, any code that needs the data from the database has to be inside the `onComplete`, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized. For examples of how to do this (and much more information), see:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

This also means that you can't return a view based on the data from the database from the `getInfoWindow` function; by the time the `` runs, the `return infoView;` runs the data from the database hasn't been loaded yet. If the caller must get the window, you'll need to pass in a custom callback, similar to the `OnCompleteListener` that you pass to Firebase. The first link in the list above has a good example of that too.